# Syntastic Not Passing Classpath to Javac

Tags: vim, javac, syntastic

I'm working in Windows, trying to use gVIM with Syntastic for a Java project, and I can't seem to get the plugin to send the Java classpath to the compiler.

Here's my `_vimrc` configuration:

```
let g:syntastic_java_checkers=['java']
let g:syntastic_java_javac_config_file_enabled = 1
```

This configures Syntastic to read the classpath from a file called `.syntastic_javac_config` in my working directory, which I have filled out with the following information (absolute paths abridged for readability):

```
let g:syntastic_java_javac_classpath = '<project root>\build\classes\main;<project root>\build\resources\main;<project root>\build\classes\test;<project root>\build resources\test'
```

The configuration above *appears* to be correct, in that I can run the command `:SyntasticJavacEditClasspath` and it shows the classpath I have configured in the config file. For some reason, though, the classpath is never being passed to `javac`. If I run the `procmon.exe` tool in Microsoft's SysinternalsSuite, I see `javac` being called with the following command line (where `<working file>` is an absolute path):

```
javac -Xlint -d %AppData%\Local\Temp\1\vim-syntastic-javac <working file>
```

Notably absent is the `-cp` parameter to configure the classpath. The result is that *all* of my imports to other classes I've written generate failures, as well as every reference to those classes in my code. Kind of useless.

I'm hoping someone can offer an idea about what might be wrong here. I've looked at the `javac.vim` file in Syntastic, but nothing sticks out as an obvious source of the problem. If anyone knows a way to step through the Vimscript, I would consider that a win as well.

Comment: Please read `:h String` in Vim.

Comment: If you're suggesting the `g:syntastic_java_javac_classpath` won't work as written, it's a good point, but that's not the problem here. I've tried escaping the backslashes, reversing them to forward slashes (which `javac` seems okay with), and using a Literal String instead, none of which resolved the issue. I've edited the OP to correct the problem.

Comment: Then please read `:h syntastic-config-debug`, and post a debug trace to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to step through using Vim's `:debug` facility, and found that the `javac` syntax checker was not splitting the classpath as I expected, looking for `\n` as a path separator rather than the path separator native to the OS (`;` in Windows, `:` on *nix). Specifying the classpath in `.syntastic_javac_config` in this manner solved the problem.

I'll do a little more research to determine if the problem is due to a misunderstanding on my end, or a bug in Syntastic, and I'll file a bug report if necessary.